# How to call bootstrap library in laravel?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I just installed bootstrap 3 via composer `composer require twbs/bootstrap` and I'm thinking how can I call the bootstrap library in my master page **default.blade.php** instead of calling via href like these : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="too many to mention">` so I can apply some style in my navigation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include ('templates.partials.navigation')
<div class = "container">
    @yield('content') {{-- @yield is always used to get content from a child page into master page. So this page will be master page. --}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**navigation.blade.php**

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href = "#">Login</a>
        <a href = "#">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I put apply the style in my navigation without importing the style link library in my master page?

Comment: read instruction on this link: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution on my question.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<div class = "navbar navbar-default">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href = "#">Login</a>
        <a href = "#">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use url()

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ url('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<div class = "navbar navbar-default">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href = "#">Login</a>
        <a href = "#">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```